# Customize Stack Exchange homepage?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, homepage

I check Stack Exchange daily for hot questions, but lately I feel the frontpage has became very noisy. With 46 sites, there is a lot of questions I'm not interested in.

Some time ago, I remember it was possible to remove any sites questions from appearing on the frontpage. Is there a reason this was removed?

Would be awesome if this could rematerialize.

Comment: We used to be able to select which sites you wanted to see the hottest questions from, but for some reason that seems to be 'replaced' by the Tag sets

Comment: @Ivo that's not "for some reason" .. that was announced some while back as the preferred/du-jour way to do this.